# How to find expected value for this financial expression

Tags: expected-value, lognormal-distribution

I am reading a research paper, and there is such condition:
$$
E_t\Big[\frac{(F_t - S_{t+1})P_t}{S_tP_{t+1}}X\Big]=0
$$

where $E_t$ is expected value. I suspect that $E_t[F_t] = F_t$ because this variable (forward exchange rate) is observable at time $t$. Variable $S_t$ is exchange rate today, $P_t$ is price level in the economy and $X$ is, simply put, another random variable.

Then, it is said that under assumption that all variables are conditionally log-normally distributed, this equation can be rewritten as:
$$
E_t(s_{t+1}) = f_t -0.5Var_t(s_{t+1})+Cov_t(s_{t+1}, p_{t+1}) - Cov_t(s_{t+1},x)
$$
where $f$, $s$, $p$ and $x$ are logarithms of $S$, $F$, $P$ and $X$.

I don't understand how can the first equation be written this way. How can I represent $E_t(s_{t+1})$ the way it is written here starting with the first equation? Could anyone direct me towards the theory that is used here?

Comment: Presumably, you make some assumption that implies $f_t$ and $p_{t+1}$ are uncorrelated?

Comment: @whuber♦  I assume that in the text I am reading, this assumption can be made. But I just in general don't understand what the steps are for getting the formula for $E_t(s_{t+1}).$

Comment: The assertion in the amended question appears to be incorrect unless you also assume (a) $X$ is independent of $P_{t+1}$  and (b) $X$ has nonzero expectation.

Comment: I rather feel that $X$ (variable which stands for marginal rate of substitution in consumption of an investor) should be dependent on $P_{t+1}$. As for (b), X indeed has nonzero expectation.

Comment: It's hard to see how to get rid of a covariance term between $X$ and $p_{t+1}$ in the calculation of that expectation, unless the covariance is zero.  The presence of $S_t$ and $P_t$ is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question changed substantially just as this answer was completed.  I am retaining the answer because it demonstrates the techniques needed to address the new question.

---

We have to make assumptions and add conditions in order to justify this calculation: $f_t$, $s_{t+1}$, and $p_{t+1}$ must have a *multivariate* normal distribution.  (This is stronger than assuming they are separately normal.)
In this case, the starting condition $\mathbb{E}_t\left[\frac{(F_t - S_{t+1})}{P_{t+1}}\right]=0$ is equivalent to

$$\mathbb{E}_t\left(\frac{F_t}{P_{t+1}}\right) = \mathbb{E}_t\left(\frac{S_{t+1}}{P_{t+1}}\right).$$

Both sides have lognormal distributions, because

$$\log\left(\frac{F_t}{P_{t+1}}\right) = \log(F_t) - \log(P_{t+1}) = f_t - p_{t+1}$$

is a linear combination of jointly normal variables and likewise for the right hand side.  Let's compute expectations (relative to the Sigma algebra at time $t$) using [basic information about multivariate lognormal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Multivariate_log-normal) and see where this goes:

$$\mathbb{E}_t\left(\frac{F_t}{P_{t+1}}\right) = \mathbb{E}_t\left(\exp(f_t - p_{t+1})\right) = \exp\left(\mathbb{E}_t(f_t - p_{t+1}) + \frac{1}{2}\text{Var}_t(f_t - p_{t+1})\right); \\
\mathbb{E}_t\left(\frac{S_{t+1}}{P_{t+1}}\right) = \mathbb{E}_t\left(\exp(s_{t+1} - p_{t+1})\right) = \exp\left(\mathbb{E}_t(s_{t+1} - p_{t+1}) + \frac{1}{2}\text{Var}_t(s_{t+1} - p_{t+1})\right).$$

Equating the right hand sides and taking logarithms yields

$$\mathbb{E}_t(f_t - p_{t+1}) + \frac{1}{2}\text{Var}_t(f_t - p_{t+1}) = \mathbb{E}_t(s_{t+1} - p_{t+1}) + \frac{1}{2}\text{Var}_t(s_{t+1} - p_{t+1}).$$

Exploiting the linearity of expectation and the bilinearity of covariance converts this into a sum of various expectations, variances, and covariances.  Many terms appear on both sides and can be cleared out.  Here's what is left:

$$\mathbb{E}_t(f_t) + \frac{1}{2}\text{Var}_t(f_t)- \text{Cov}(f_t, p_{t+1})\\ = \mathbb{E}_t(s_{t+1}) + \frac{1}{2}\text{Var}_t(s_{t+1})  - \text{Cov}(s_{t+1}, p_{t+1}).$$

At time $t$, $f_t$ is *constant* (almost surely) and therefore can be identified with its expectation.  The covariances with random variables are zero and so is its variance.  These observations simplify the preceding to

$$f_t = \mathbb{E}_t(s_{t+1}) + \frac{1}{2}\text{Var}_t(s_{t+1}) - \text{Cov}(s_{t+1}, p_{t+1}),$$

which is the desired formula.

Comment: ♦  Brilliant! Thank you a lot for your answer. The author in the paper I am trying to understand (Charles Engel, Journal of Empirical Finance 3 (1996), page 150) didn't explicitly mention that the variables have multivariate normal distribution, but it could be the case. Anyway, it's so great that I can unfold the logic now.